# Find data in multi-column a table and return the value of a neighbouring cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

UPDATED WITH REAL DATA

So I have the following tables in the same spreadsheet: [Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofiM2.png) and [Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTLyM.png).

In cell K197 and below (Table 2) I need a formula that looks in all cells of Table 1 for the value in cell G197 and below (Table 2) and returns the value of the cell to the right of the matching cell of Table 1. The result should look like what is currently in Table 2. **In other words**, I need to search Table 1 for each unique code listed in Table 2 (column G) and return their isolation status (blank or "Isolating") in Table 2 (column K).

It is worth noting that samples that are isolating may or may not be grouped together like showed in Table 1, so the function in Table 2 (column K) needs to be able to find any sample anywhere in Table 1 and pair it with its isolation status.

I have tried VLOOKUP but don't seem to be able to have the col_index argument automatically point to the column next to the matching result (e.g. using COLUMN). Also tried INDEX+MATCH but that seems to work for only two columns at a time, and I am not sure if it's possible to to repeat the function in the same cell to have it apply to the rest of the columns in Table 1. I know this can be made easy by using a different table layout, but there is a practical reason why Table 1 should be the way it is.

I hope this makes some sense and look forward to any tips!

Comment: if every 8th item is "isolating", you could use `=IF(OR((RIGHT(G197,5)+0)-1=0,MOD((RIGHT(G197,5)+0)-1,8)=0),"Isolating","")` but im guessing that is just sample data and not the case ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately that is not the case. Items that are isolating may be grouped together (as shown in updated question) or randomly interspersed across the table. If I could translate the formula into words, I would need to search Table 1 for each unique code listed in Table 2 (column G) and return their isolation status (blank or "Isolating") in Table 2 (column K).

Answer (score 0):

The comments below are from a Tip i sent out on using the Column Function to make copying VLOOKUPS quicker. This might help assuming the date table 1 is in the same order as Table 2.  A couple screen caps or sample data might help explain what you are looking for.

---

The column function might make things a bit easier for you.

The COLUMN Function simply provides the column number of a cell.  In the example below I just entered =COLUMN(). It provides me the column number of the column it is in.

[image]

So in the screen cap above you will 1 in cell A1 as it is in the first column, 2 in B1 as it is in the second column…

If I enter =COLUMN(??), where ?? is any letter(s), and a number it will provide the column number. So below I used =COLUMN(AA1) and it returns a 27 as AA is the 27th column in Excel.

[image]

So if I wanted to create a VLOOKUP against a table with a lot of data looking to get the information elsewhere in the same order I could use the COLUMN formula in my VLOOKUP to save time when creating the formulas.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Nesting COLUMN into VLOOKUP is what I was trying to do, but ideally I would need COLUMN to return the column number of the same value that I am VLOOKing up (as found in Table 1), so that by adding a "+1"  I can point to the cell to its right. Basically, is there a formula to return the column number or address of a reference that is being looked up?

Comment: Hi Francesco, See if this helps.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847134/excel-how-to-get-the-cell-address-of-a-hlookup-reference

Comment: I was going to suggest match